# Proper way to structure a "notes" table for multiple data sets?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, data-structures, database-schema

Please excuse the title, I had trouble wording my question without being overly descriptive.

My application has tables likes these:
**contacts**
**properties**
**events**

I am adding a method of attaching **notes** to the items in the above tables.    I would like it so that a single note can associate with a contact, property or event (or a combination of the three).

Currently my **notes** table looks like this:

> noteID int
>   noteCreated datatime
>   noteContent text
>   userID int (*userid that created the note*)
>   **contactID int
>
>   propertyID int
>
>   eventID int**

The portion in question is in bold.  Right now, when I create a **note for an event**, I simply insert the note and also set the **eventID**.  If the event also **relates to a contact**, I can add the **contactID** as well (contactID and eventID would be set).  While it works, I think it is inefficient and not properly normalized.

What I am trying to do is create a one-to-many relationship, problem is that the "many" part can have  different target tables.  At the same time I want to reduce the number of queries necessary to select or insert a note.

My thought was to create a table that connects them together, then give properties, contacts, and events their own unique targetType that stays constant. But I still feel that is not the best way to do it.  Alternatively I can create a separate relationship table for each target table (notes_properties, notes_contacts, etc...).

> noteID int
>   targetID int
>   targetType int

Much help would be appreciated.  Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question and phrasing it more clearly than I could have.  I always seem to end up going with a different solution depending on the way the notes will be used, and where the added complexity would cause me the least amount of hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship between notes and contacts, properties & events is 1 to 1, e.g., a contact can have only one note, then the best way to model it would be to simply add a `noteID` column to the contact, properties and events table.

If it's a many-to-many relationship, e.g., a contact can have many notes, then you would want to create a separate table, say `contact_notes` with two columns - `contactID` and `noteID`.

Don't get hung up on the fact that a note can be associated to multiple entities.  It really doesn't affect the way you model it at all.

Comment: So you'd just add a table for each many-many relationship, ie `contact_notes`, `property_notes`, `event_notes`, right?  And if you wanted to add notes to some other future table it's as easy as adding another intermediate table: `venue_notes`, eg.

Comment: Thank you, Eric! This is one of the structures I had in mind, but didn't want to deal with creating so many tables.  I will also be adding "files" to each of the things.  This is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm stunned at the amazing help I'm receiving.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing...

> I would like it so that a single note can associate with a contact, property or event (or a combination of the three).

...is a variation of a classic many-to-many relationship (with the additional assumption that a contact, property or event can have more than one note and the additional complication of dealing with four tables instead of two).

The way to properly normalize that situation is with an intermediate table with the fields as you've described in your question:

```
noteID int
targetID int
targetType int
```

As you point out though, this will make certain queries harder to write and more inefficient.  Specifically, outer joins (which you'll almost certainly need since I'm sure notes are optional) will have to use subqueries.

I'd suggest denormalizing slightly and going with an intermediate table that looks like this:

```
ID int          'autonumber to provide a reliable and efficient unique key'
noteID int
contactID int   'allow nulls'
propertyID int  'allow nulls'
eventID int     'allow nulls'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to keep all the notes in a single table I would recommend a structure like this:

```
noteID
noteCreated
noteContent 
userID
noteType (contact, property or event)
RelatedID
```

then you can join using:

```
FROM Contacts C
INNER JOIN Notes N on C.ID = N.RelatedID and N.noteType = 'contact'
```

or

```
FROM Property P
INNER JOIN Notes N on P.ID = N.RelatedID and N.noteType = 'property'
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that you will only see `Contacts` or `Property` records that have associated `Note` records.  If they don't have a `Note` associated they will be excluded from the INNER JOIN.

Comment: To make matters worse, `FROM Contacts C LEFT JOIN Notes N on C.ID = N.RelatedID and N.noteType = 'contact'` won't work either.  You'd actually have to do this: `FROM Contacts C LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Notes on C.ID = Notes.RelatedID and Notes.noteType = 'contact') N`  It gets annoying and inefficient fast.